# кнопки удалить и редактировать

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на кнопку Удалить, данный блок исчезает. При нажатии на Редактировать блок переходит в состояние редактирования

```js
    let deleteBNT = document.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementsByName('btn-delete')
        deleteBNT.parentNode.removeChild(deleteBNT);
    deleteBNT = document.getElementsByName('btn-delete')
    });

    let editBNT = document.addEventListener('click', function () {
    
    })
```

```css
.cotainer {
    background: #BFBFBF;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 15px;
}

.delete {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.edit {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

textarea {
    width: 350px;
    height: 120px;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #BFBFBF;
}
.activ{
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cotainer">
    <div class="block">
        <button class="delete" name="btn-delete">delete</button>
        <button class="edit" name="btn-edit">edit</button>
        <textarea readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, cumque ea illum impedit itaque labore laudantium quam quod reprehenderit sunt.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cotainer">
    <div class="block">
        <button class="delete " name="btn-delete">delete</button>
        <button class="edit" name="btn-edit">edit</button>
        <textarea readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto cumque deleniti distinctio dolor eos est, fuga rem sequi ullam velit.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="cotainer">
    <div class="block">
        <button class="delete" name="btn-delete">delete</button>
        <button class="edit" name="btn-edit">edit</button>
        <textarea readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias atque aut cum, exercitationem fugiat magni molestias praesentium tenetur totam voluptatibus.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

как реализовать удаление блока
и как реализовать что бы при нажании на "edit" в "textarea" удалялся атрибут "readonly"

```
   function removeDiv(btnstate){
        let DelDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('blocks')
        DelDiv.parentNode.removeChild(DelDiv)
    }
```

Comment: Если накопипастить блоков, то так солиднее? `class="cotainer"` ))))

Comment: ну принципи можна и без него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let deleteBNT = document.addEventListener(` - ??

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

> Return value
>
> undefined

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.cotainer .delete').forEach(del =>
  del.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.closest('.cotainer').remove();
  })
);
```

```css
.cotainer {
  background: #BFBFBF;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.delete {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.edit {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

textarea {
  width: 350px;
  height: 120px;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #BFBFBF;
}

.activ {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cotainer">
  <div class="block">
    <button class="delete" name="btn-delete">delete</button>
    <button class="edit" name="btn-edit">edit</button>
    <textarea readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, cumque ea illum impedit itaque labore laudantium quam quod reprehenderit sunt.</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cotainer">
  <div class="block">
    <button class="delete " name="btn-delete">delete</button>
    <button class="edit" name="btn-edit">edit</button>
    <textarea readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto cumque deleniti distinctio dolor eos est, fuga rem sequi ullam velit.</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cotainer">
  <div class="block">
    <button class="delete" name="btn-delete">delete</button>
    <button class="edit" name="btn-edit">edit</button>
    <textarea readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias atque aut cum, exercitationem fugiat magni molestias praesentium tenetur totam voluptatibus.</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему через getElementsByClassName не можна удалить блок (добавил в вопрос другую функцию), а когда заменил на getElementsById и добавил блоку id смог удалить

Comment: @Bohdan https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.cotainer').forEach(cotainer => {
  const textarea = cotainer.querySelector('textarea');
  cotainer.querySelector('.edit').addEventListener('click', () => textarea.removeAttribute('readonly'));
  textarea.onblur = () => textarea.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```